# all subjects in same table in my sheetmark

Tags: php

What do I need to change from below code in order to get all the subjects in the same table?

```
<?php
include('grade.php');
$mysubject = $grade->getsubject();
?>
    <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website.     It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more   &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach($mysubject as $row): ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 gradeform">
        <div class="form_hover " style="background-color: #428BCA;">
            <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o" style="font-size:   147px;color:#fff;"></i>
            </p>

            <div class="header">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="header-text">
                    <div class="panel panel-success" style="height: 247px;">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 style="color: #428BCA;">Subject: <?php echo  $row['subject'];?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tr class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <th>TD</th>
                                    <th>Exam</th>
                                    <th>catching</th>
                                    <th>average</th>

                                </tr>
                                <?php $mygrade = $grade-  >getgrade($row['id']); ?>                                
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $mygrade['att1']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $mygrade['exam1']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $mygrade['quiz1']; ?></td> 
                                   <td><?php echo $mygrade['project1']; ?></td> 
                                </tr>

                            </table> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <?php $teacher = $grade->getteacher($row['id']); ?>
                                <label>Teacher: <?php echo $teacher;?></label><br />
                                <label>Semester: <?php echo $row['sem']?> Sem</label><br />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Uhmm... what? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: i have every subject in différent table

Comment: You need to show us the structure of `$mysubject`. We cannot even begin to help with the limited information you have given.

Comment: juste about css  not about php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have every subject in différent table

The problem is, in each iteration of `foreach` loop you're creating a new table. If you want to display all the subjects under one table, just take the `<table>` outside of your `foreach` loop, like this:

```
// your code

<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 gradeform">
        <div class="form_hover " style="background-color: #428BCA;">
            <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o" style="font-size:   147px;color:#fff;"></i>
            </p>

            <div class="header">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="header-text">
                    <div class="panel panel-success" style="height: 247px;">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <?php foreach($mysubject as $row): ?>
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 style="color: #428BCA;">Subject: <?php echo  $row['subject'];?></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <tr class="alert alert-danger">
                                        <th>TD</th>
                                        <th>Exam</th>
                                        <th>catching</th>
                                        <th>average</th>

                                    </tr>
                                    <?php $mygrade = $grade-  >getgrade($row['id']); ?>                                
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $mygrade['att1']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $mygrade['exam1']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $mygrade['quiz1']; ?></td> 
                                       <td><?php echo $mygrade['project1']; ?></td> 
                                    </tr>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <?php $teacher = $grade->getteacher($row['id']); ?>
                                        <label>Teacher: <?php echo $teacher;?></label><br />
                                        <label>Semester: <?php echo $row['sem']?> Sem</label><br />
                                    </div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </table> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```